# Domain Modelling tool advice - cross project relationships and inheritance

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, domain-model

We're after an ORM/Domain Modelling tool that will allow us to generate several related domain models across multiple projects/assemblies generated in a "database first" approach from our MSSQL database. We need some help working out which tools will meet our needs.

Requirements are:

1. Cross project relationships

   - Our domain is split into numerous modules and for each client (whom we give source code to) we don't use all modules and so we'd like to "unplug" all the logic they don't need to see or get access to.
   - For example, we want to store a shared data (mostly common lookup information) in it's own common assembly.
   - We don't need two-way relationships between models (because that would cause a circular reference). Only the child end of relationship would get generated.
2. Cross project inheritance

   - Similar to above, we want to be able to abstract common functionality into base classes in one domain model and inherit them.
   - Note: Inheritance links between domains will be limited, only one or two per sub-domain.
   - Note: It shouldn't matter, but we are using "Table per Type" or "[Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)" to model our inheritance in our relational (DB) schema
3. Generated classes are to be:

   1. Marked with DataContract/DataMember attributes
   2. Notify of property changes (via INotifyPropertyChanged implementations)
   3. Have partial On*PropertyName*Changed() methods (e.g. as per Linq to SQL and Entity Framework generated objects)
   4. (Ideal, but not necessary) Related collection types should implement INotifyCollectionChanged.

Any feedback as to any ORM tools that support (or have workarounds to support) these criteria would be appreciated!

NOTE: Tools we've looked at (but this doesn't rule them out entirely):

- [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed) (lovely, but doesn't support cross project inheritance easily).
- [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) (complicated and all encompassing, but when grouping using `AsSeparateProjects` mode it didn't seem to support cross-model relationships let alone inheritance).
- Entity Framework (I just got lost... The designer story when [splitting the domain across multiple models](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx) wasn't very nice).

Comment: LLBLGen Pro doesn't support connections over groups when AsSeparateProjects is selected because the model will result in multiple vs.net projects. If we'd allow the connections across group boundaries (as you requested), the vs.net projects would end up referencing each other, which isn't possible, as it would result in cyclic references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely needs small Proof-of-concept project because your requirements are not something that is commonly described in papers about EF.

For 1. and 2. go through these articles ([part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/24/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-1.aspx), [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx)) and try to make simple solution wich will proof that you are able to use both relations and inheritance among multiple EDMXs.

The last point will be satisfied by custom T4 template for generating classes from EDMX - start with POCO template and alter its generation features.

Comment: For the record on this one: after a lot of proof of concept work we are using Entity Framework. Were are using a self-build custom command line tool similar to EdmGen2 to do all the CSDL stuff mentioned in Part 2 linked above while still using the designer. It all hangs together quite nicely and easily now! I hope to blog it soon - so watch this space.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it might sounds like the reverse of what you're asking for, I'd probably look at [EF Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx). Because it's all built on top of POCOs, DbSets and a DbContext class, you'll be able to get the inheritance working pretty easily.

Have your shared models and an abstract DbContext in the common assembly. Have the specific models and final DbContext in the customer specific assemblies.

On the WinForms front, there's [example code here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/16/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-and-winforms-databinding.aspx) for how to make the sets observable. You'll need to take care of INotifyPropertyChanged yourself but that's pretty easy.

The downside of EF Code First for you will be that there's no way to just generate all the classes. That being said, they're simple enough to write that I'd probably just write them on an as-needed basis while you code the rest of the app. Any form of generic, automated tool would have trouble working out which models and properties belong in common vs customer-specific.

Comment: My immediate reaction to EF Code First is that the POCO's are so plain - which is the point really I suppose... Really we want support for numerous aspects on top of the POCO without having to hand write them all. For example, INotifyPropertyChanged support and partial "On...Changed" methods. The reality is the bulk of key domain behaviors are implemented in the On..Changed, property changed reactions of related entities, and property validation. That is, all the goodies that we usually add to the partial classes on top of a generated model (except the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation).